# KBinsDiscretizer bin edges

Tags: python, scikit-learn, binning

Does anyone know if the bin edges provided by KBinsDiscretizer have to be interpreted?
Since it uses numpy linspace for uniform binning and the default is `endpoint=True` the bins should include the rightmost edge. So how do I write that with greater-than and less-than signs?

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer
iris_data = load_iris()
x = iris_data.data
# binning of first feature
est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='onehot-dense', strategy='uniform')
x1 = est.fit_transform(x[:,0].reshape(-1, 1))
bin_edges = est.bin_edges_
```

The bin edges are [4.3, 5.5, 6.7, 7.9]. So is it correct to write it like this?

1. bin: 4.3 <= x < 5.5,
2. bin: 5.5 <= x < 6.7,
3. bin: 6.7 <= x <= 7.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The edges are defined using `np.linspace` but the assignment is done using `np.digitize` followed by a `np.clip` to rein in the right most bins, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b3ea3ed6a/sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py#L21) line 303:

```
for jj in range(Xt.shape[1]):
   rtol = 1.e-5
   atol = 1.e-8
   eps = atol + rtol * np.abs(Xt[:, jj])
   Xt[:, jj] = np.digitize(Xt[:, jj] + eps, bin_edges[jj][1:])
np.clip(Xt, 0, self.n_bins_ - 1, out=Xt)
```

The [default](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) for np.digitize is `right=False` , so your bins are mostly correct, if applied to this data. You can check with the boundaries:

```
test = np.array([4.3,5.5,6.7,7.9]).reshape(-1,1)

est.transform(test)
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

You should note that if you have values that are beyond your bin edge, they are automatically assigned to the boundary bin, see [np.digitize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html). So this means, we try with out of bound values 4.1 and 8.1:

```
test = np.array([4.1,4.3,7.9,8.1]).reshape(-1,1)
est.transform(test)

array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

They are assigned to the first and last bin respectively. So strictly speaking, the bins are:

```
1. bin: x < 5.5,
2. bin: 5.5 <= x < 6.7,
3. bin: 6.7 <= x
```

Comment: Using KBinsDiscretizer `discretizer = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=6, encode='ordinal', strategy='quantile')` how could I print the range of evrery bin created for every feature that I pass in the discretizer?

Comment: Hi @ChristosKarapapas, this does not seem to be related to the question. I can try to answer just this time, you can look under the attribute `discretizer.bin_edges_`